# How to see the Value of an integer in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

An integer I have in my code keeps changing values, and I want to see what value it has each time. Is there a way to see the value while the program is running?

Comment: In general, you can put your cursor over the method in question (`WriteLine`) and hit F1. This will open the MSDN help page for that particular method, where you can see which overloads with which parameters are available. As you can see, [there *is* a `string, object` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-6.0#system-console-writeline(system-string-system-object)) that would fit your purpose, but you need to modify your first string. Exercise: Can you find out yourself by reading the doc how you'd need to modify it?

Comment: "but nothing happened" - you mean, you dont' even see "Value:" in the console? Is your program a console program at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.WriteLine($"Value = {equalElement}");

Comment: Or, if we want to keep the overload used by OP: `Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", equalElements);`

Comment: You should explain code rather than just give it blindly to the user. That's one of the things that makes a good answer. Also, please apply formatting, this is pretty lazy as it stands.